# Выборка данных по дате Mongo

Tags: node.js, mongo

В моей базе данных есть поле lastLogin там записана дата объект Date.
Как я могу написать запрос чтобы получить все записи за последние три дня или одну любую запись за последние три дня?

```
const user = await User.find({lastLogin: {$lt:new ObjectId( Math.floor(new Date(new Date()-1000*60*60*24*60).getTime()/1000).toString(16) + "0000000000000000" )}})
```

Пробовал так, но вернулся пустой массив

Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Наверное, уже поздно, но попробуй это: https://www.codecamp.ru/blog/mongodb-query-date-range/

Comment: [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным. — [из очереди проверок](/review/late-answers/829526)